# Set option of a list to selected from controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I was wondering if there is a better way of setting the option to selected, preferably from the controller (I don't want much code in my view).

My thought is to set it to have a list with my 3 options; none of which are selected. Then on the GET action of that view, to set the value (by the id of that option / select list) to selected based on the role . I am just unsure how to access the id of the list and options from the controller.

```
 <select class="form-control">
            @{
                switch (@Model.Role)
                {
                    case "User":
                        {
                            <option selected="selected">User</option>
                            <option>Investigator</option>
                            <option>Admin</option>
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Investigator":
                        {
                            <option>User</option>
                            <option selected="selected">Investigator</option>
                            <option>Admin</option>
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Admin":
                        {
                            <option>User</option>
                            <option>Investigator</option>
                            <option selected="selected">Admin</option>
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        </select>
```

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and work through some tutorials to understand the basics. In particular how to use html helpers - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.yourProperty, Model.yourCollection)`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a SelectListItem with DropDownList?

**Controller**

```
  model.Roles.Insert(0,new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "", Selected=true });
```

**View**

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedRole, Model.Roles)
```